# Wordpress / PHP: check if post is in only in one category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Basically, I want to hide the category list if the author hasn't chosen a category for the post yet (so that it doesn't show 'uncategorised' on the archive page).

I need to check if the post is ONLY in the 'uncategorised' category in Wordpress. 
I am checking if the post is in this category with:

```
<?php if (!in_category( 'uncategorised' )) { ?>
    <div class="category">
        <?php the_category(', '); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Which works great - however **any** post that is in 'uncategorised' AND another category is also not appearing. So, i need to also check if that is the ONLY category it is in. So something like '`&& is only in one category`' is what i'm looking for, but my google searches have not come up with any solutions.

Please could someone point me in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built in function that could help you here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Example of ”only one category”:

```
$categories = get_the_category()

if ( count($categories) == 1 ) { ... }
```